# AlertDialog show() giving WindowManager BadTokenException

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm getting a lot of reports of that exception on Google Play developer console, and I can't understand why, because I can't reproduce the error, it works perfectly on all my devices.

This is the source code of my custom AlertDialog and the line of the crash is on the `show()` call at the end of the method. What is wrong?

I checked some questions related here in Stack Overflow but I'm actually using `final` when declaring the dialog, which is the solution of other questions, and I'm still having the exception reports.

```
public static void showPoliciesDialog(final Activity activity, final Runnable runnable) {
    int sw = App.getInstance().getSmallSideSize();
    final int LIGHT_GRAY = 0xFFc7c7c7;

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.PolicyStyle));
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(activity);
    ll.setPadding((int)(sw*0.025), 0, (int)(sw*0.025), 0);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final TextView title = new TextView(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams titleLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    titleLP.setMargins( Util.dpToPx(activity, 15), Util.dpToPx(activity, 15), Util.dpToPx(activity, 15), Util.dpToPx(activity, 15) );
    title.setLayoutParams(titleLP );
    title.setTextSize(18);
    title.setText(R.string.POLICY_TITLE);
    title.setTextColor(0xFF307282); // Blue color
    ll.addView(title);

    final CheckBox acceptCheckbox = new CheckBox(activity);
    acceptCheckbox.setTextColor(LIGHT_GRAY);
    acceptCheckbox.setText(R.string.I_WANT_DATA_COLLECT);
    acceptCheckbox.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
    acceptCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    acceptCheckbox.setChecked(App.getInstance().retrieveBooleanValue(Constants.SEND_DATA_CHECKBOX, ConfigManager.getInstance().defaultStorable()));
    acceptCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                App.getInstance().storeBooleanValue(Constants.SEND_DATA_CHECKBOX, isChecked);
            }
        }
    );
    acceptCheckbox.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

    // Detects if the end of the web page has been reached & in this case it shows the accept checkbox.
    // Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956443/android-making-a-button-visible-once-webview-is-done-scrolling
    // And on
    // [1] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794647/detect-if-webview-scroll-reach-the-end
    // [2] - (To avoid use of an deprecated method) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079863/how-get-webview-scale-in-android-4
    final WebView policiesWebView = new WebView(activity){
        float currentScale = -1;
        {
            this.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
                    super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
                    currentScale = newScale;
                }
            });
            this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
            // Only called on Android versions where onScaleChanged is not called
            if(currentScale == -1)
                currentScale = this.getScale();
            int height = (int) Math.floor(this.getContentHeight() * currentScale);
            int webViewHeight = this.getHeight();
            int cutoff = height - webViewHeight - 10; // Don't be too strict on the cutoff point
            if (t >= cutoff) {
                // We need to know if it's necessary to show the accept checkbox. It should be visible only if it's not the first time that this dialog has been showed, so only
                // if the policies have been accepted previously. if we have the key stored, then, it's not the first time this dialog is being showed, so we must show the accept checkbox
                if(App.getInstance().containsKey(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED)){
                    acceptCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    policiesWebView.loadUrl(ConfigManager.getInstance().getPrivacyUrl());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams policiesWebViewLayoutParams =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
    policiesWebViewLayoutParams.weight=1;
    policiesWebView.setLayoutParams(policiesWebViewLayoutParams);
    policiesWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ll.addView(policiesWebView);
    ll.addView(acceptCheckbox);

    final TextView readPolicies = new TextView(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams readPoliciesLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    readPoliciesLP.setMargins( Util.dpToPx(activity, 15), 0, Util.dpToPx(activity, 10), Util.dpToPx(activity, 30) );
    readPolicies.setPadding(0,0,0,Util.dpToPx(activity, 20));
    readPolicies.setTextColor(LIGHT_GRAY);
    readPolicies.setLayoutParams(readPoliciesLP);
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(activity.getString(R.string.PLEASE_READ_POLICIES));
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
    readPolicies.setText(content);
    readPolicies.setTextSize(16);
    readPolicies.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    readPolicies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            policiesWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            readPolicies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    ll.addView(readPolicies);

    // We need to know if we should treat this buttonas an agree button or a back button.
    // Agree mode: If it's the first time this dialog is being showed. Policies has not been accepted previously.
    // Back mode: If it's not the first time. The policies has been accepted previously.
    String buttonText = App.getInstance().containsKey(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED) == false ? activity.getString(R.string.AGREE) : activity.getString(R.string.BACK);

    builder.setPositiveButton(buttonText,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(App.getInstance().containsKey(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED) == false) { //if agree mode
                    App.getInstance().storeBooleanValue(Constants.SEND_DATA_CHECKBOX, true);
                    App.getInstance().storeBooleanValue(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED, true);
                }

                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                if(runnable != null)
                    runnable.run();
            }
        }
    );

    // We will show close app button only if it's the first time we show this dialog.
    if(App.getInstance().containsKey(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED) == false)
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.CLOSE_APP,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    //launching navigator with non accept policies text
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    String url = "https://myurl.com/no-terms.php?idApp={appId}";
                    url=GlobalVariablesManager.getInstance().replaceValues(url, false, false);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(URLParser.parse(url)));
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);

                    //App.getInstance().storeBooleanValue(Constants.PRIVACY_POLICIES_ACCEPTED, false);
                    SectionManager.getInstance().exit(false);
                    App.getInstance().clean();
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
        );

    builder.setView(ll);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // This will set the color of negative button to a gray color
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
            Button buttonNegative = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            buttonNegative.setTextColor(LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this error myself awhile back. Here is the useful insight I got from Crashlytics:

"This crash is usually caused by your app trying to display a dialog using a previously-finished Activity as a context. For example, this can happen if an Activity triggers an AsyncTask that tries to display a dialog when it is finished, but the user navigates back from the Activity before the task is completed."

Crashlytics Suggested Links: 
[Android – Displaying Dialogs From Background Threads](http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads/) 
 [Error : BinderProxy@45d459c0 is not valid; is your activity running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811993/error-binderproxy45d459c0-is-not-valid-is-your-activity-running)

Comment: thank you, solved it adding an if (activity.isFinishing() == false)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for BadTokenException:

> ```
>  Exception that is thrown when trying to add view whose
>  {@link LayoutParams} {@link LayoutParams#token}
>  is invalid.
> ```

This token is given to the activity on it's attach method, so i'm guessing you're trying to show the dialog too soon in some cases. try to post the show method in a post block

Comment: why too soon? what do you mean?

Comment: This whould be a good solution? 
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    dialog.show();
   }
  }, 1000);

Comment: Whoops, sorry, don't know why i wrote delayed, no reason to actually delay it, just post it on the main thread so that i executes at the end of the queue.

So 
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.show();      
            }
        });
Will work fine.

Is this code running from the main thread? if so there's no need to get the main looper, if not then it'll not work anyway

Comment: Whoops again, meant it wouldn't have worked without the post, also wanted to say that if you run it after onStart or something like that you should probably be ok 2...

Comment: thanks for your help but finally the other solution was the correct one